# Subversion: How to find the buggy commit?

Tags: svn

I have a problem that someone introduced a bug but I do not know the subversion commit that introduced this bug. I am looking for something like the nice git feature [bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) for svn.

Does anyone know scripts like e.g. python to simulate this feature?

Comment: I had heard about the feature (I'm not a git user), but that really looks awesome in the documentation (that I took the liberty to link into the question).

Comment: A Google search for "svn bisect" gives you pretty good hits, you know ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

svn does **not** have a bisect-like feature built in. There appears to be a [perl script](http://search.cpan.org/~infinoid/App-SVN-Bisect-1.0/bin/svn-bisect) available to do it.

svn-blame does **not** do the same thing as git-bisect; it is equivalent to git-blame and hg-annotate.

Answer (score -3):

[`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html) might help you. GUI interfaces provide a nice-looking "implementation" of this:

[image: TSVN Blame]

Comment: this is not quite what i am looking for because I do know neiter the source file nor do i recognize the faulty lines that will lead to the bug. I like to test the finished build and get a good or bad then continue with the next bisec interval/half.